# I was trying to implement an update view that adds +1 to a specific integer field. In the view function, a not defied error occurs

Tags: django, view

I was trying to implement an update view that adds +1 to a specific integer field.

In the view function, a not defied error occurs.

error

```
NameError: name 'grade' is not defined
```

button

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url "bestlec:request_grade_plus" p.pk %}"> recommandation </a>
```

url pattern

```
    path('<int:id>/grade_plus/', views.grade_plus, name="request_grade_plus"),
```

model

```
class Best20(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    url_lec = models.CharField(max_length= 60)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=True)
    # grade = models.CharField(max_length= 30)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
```

view

```
    def grade_plus (request, id):
        Best20.objects.filter (Q (id = id)). Update (grade = grade +1)
        print ('grade +1 success')
        return redirect ('')
```

Please let me know if you know how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Add your model details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't user filed name in the query as grade = grade +1. It should be like this.

```
from django.db.models import F

Best20.objects.filter (Q (id = id)).update(grade = F('gradle') + 1)
```

Comment: I did it the way you told me, and the problem was solved.

Thank you for giving me a convenient and good solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import F

Best20.objects.filter(id=id).update(grade=F('grade')+1)
```

since you are using the column of the same model you need to use `F` function to do that.

Comment: thanks for let me know but I think the method you gave me is the same as the comment above ^^ ;;